# Issues with Master admission because of transfer to another university during undergraduate studies

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, transcript-of-records

This year I'm trying to get into the Master's program. There is one particular university where I want to get into, say its name is X.

X is asking me to provide transcripts of my **all** previous higher education programs, even **uncompleted** ones.

The thing is that during my undergraduate studies I've transferred from one higher institution to another. The first university was one of the best programs in my country, it featured many hours of great courses and so on. However, because of my not very good performance there I had to transfer to another university. During my studies in the first university, I got 6 Bs and 2 Cs and a couple of passes which yielded a GPA of 2.85.

Now, I'm in the last (4th) year of bachelor studies in the second university and got a GPA of around 3.4. It is worth mentioning that while transferring some grades from my previous university got matched to classes of the second university (and thus some Cs and Bs from the first university were added to the transcript from the second university), so I can be admitted to the second year.

Fast forward to the actual question. As I am **highly dependant** on scholarship, I feel like if I mention my first higher institution experience and attach a transcript for it I won't be able to get a scholarship here. If I don't mention it though, I will create a chance to be rejected because of a discrepancy in my portfolio, as in the transcript from my second university it is mentioned that the standard period of study on my program is 4 years. And it is also stated that I was enrolled in 2018 and will be graduating in 2021 (3 years here), exactly because I was admitted to the second year.

I don't want to violate any rules, but, even though I have a solid portfolio (in my opinion), I feel that If I will attach a transcript from my first university the race for a scholarship will be pretty much over for me, so I don't really have anything to lose here and it's might be worth trying to take a risk. I also think that there is a small chance that admission committee members won't notice the discrepancy.

What would you do in my situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't lie.  They asked for all your transcripts, so if you omit one then your application is fraudulent. Even if you're admitted to this masters program, fraud in your application should be sufficient reason to expel you if it's discovered later.

Comment: The second university should note on the transcript that credits were transferred.  This will allow the masters program to detect the fraud before admissions.